# To Implement the searcView for Contacts stored in RecyclerView in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I am storing the contacts details of phone in my app using recyclerView.

Here is how I have fetch the contacts

```
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------checking for  permission
void showContacts() {
    // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
        contactsList=getContactNames();
        Toast.makeText(this,contactsList.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,contactsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Do your work.
                showContacts();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we cannot proceed further", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Contacts fatching

```
private ArrayList<Contact_Object> getContactNames() {
    ArrayList<Contact_Object> mContacts=new ArrayList<>();
    //Get the ContentResolver
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null,    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");

    // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {// Iterate through the cursor
        do {// Get the contacts name
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            mContacts.add(new Contact_Object(name,number));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

     mContacts.add(new Contact_Object(na,num));

    // Close the curosor
    cursor.close();

    return mContacts;
}
```

Following is the menu resource file

```
  <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_contact"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
 </menu>
```

Now I am trying to implement the searchView  like  this 
and this is thee  part  I am getting  error,hoping some problem in threading concept anyone please rectify..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_list, menu);

    final MenuItem search=menu.findItem(R.id.search_contact);
    searchView= (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (!searchView.isIconified()){
                searchView.setIconified(true);
            }
           //  search.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

           final List<Contact_Object> filterModel=filter(contactsList,newText);
              adapter.setFilter(filterModel);
            return true;
        }
    });


private List<Contact_Object> filter(List<Contact_Object> p,String query){
    query=query.toLowerCase();
    final List<Contact_Object> filterContacts=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Contact_Object model:p){
        String text=model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.startsWith(query)){
            filterContacts.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filterContacts;
}
```

this is the error
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference